# What exactly do the items Last Whisper and Void Staff do?

Tags: league-of-legends

Both Last Whisper (+ Lord Dominicks Regards and Mortal Reminder) and Void Staff give a percentage of Magic Penetration and Armor Penetration.

What does this mean? The wording on the Last Whisper (and the items that build from it) say X% bonus armor penetration. Does this mean it gives me X% of the armor penetration I have? Or does it ignore X% of my opponent's armor total?

Comment: Void Staff doesnt give bonus Magic Pen, it ignores 35% of magic resistance. It says so in the effect http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Void_Staff

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why this was downvoted. Many LoL questions are about super specific scenarios or what builds to go with, but this question asks an objective question with an objective answer...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Every champion in League of Legends has armor and magic resistance stats. Even marksmen, who typically don't build any defensive items other than Guardian Angel or Mercurial Scimitar, have some **base** resistances that reduces damage.

When you buy defensive items, you are often getting additional armor or magic resistance stats. This additional value is called **bonus** resistances.

[Last Whisper](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Last_Whisper) (and its subsequent items) penetrates only *bonus* armor. That means that base armor is ignored.

For example, using completely fictional numbers, let's say we have a champion that has 10 base armor that has purchased 90 armor, for a total armor stat of 100. Last Whisper will reduce his armor rating by 27 (30% of 90), leaving his total armor stat at 73. As another example, a champion with 90 base armor and 10 bonus armor will only have his armor rating reduced by 3 (30% of 10), leaving his total armor stat at 97.

[Void Staff](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Void_Staff) is a little different - it ignores 35% of the *total* magic resist. So using the two sample champions from before, no matter what their ratio of base vs. bonus magic resist is, they would both have their 100 total magic resistance changed to 65.

Comment: This is incorrect for void staff. The effect on void staff is that it ignores 35% of magic resist, not gains 35% bonus Mpen

Comment: @BenCraig Ah, you're right. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Nice answer. It may be helpful to users if you provide links to the relevant pages on the wiki, like [Last Whisper](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Last_Whisper)

Comment: Oh, makes sense. The "Bonus" in the armor pen ones confused me, as I interpreted it differently.